# Google Chrome Angular - CAUTION: request is not finished yet

Tags: angular, google-chrome, loading

In my angular application I am calling the get endpoint:
https://example.test.de/example-1/rest-api/persons

This endpoint is returning some simple data. In postman I can call the endpoint without any problems and I get a quick response.
When I open the Angular UI in firefox, the endpoint is also returning quick results.

When I open the app in Google Chrome, the endpoint is never returning any value and in the network tab I can just see:
CAUTION: request is not finished yet!

I thought maybe this is a caching issue so I opened a Google Chrome Inkognito tab, but there its also not working. However its getting even stranger: sometimes its working even in Google Chrome but sometimes not. It seems super random.

In the Angular Service I am doing this:

```
public getPersons(): Observable<Person[]> {
    const headers = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.keycloakService.getKeycloakInstance().token)
        .set('Content-Type', 'applciation/json')
    };
    let url = this.getApplicationBaseUrl();
    url =
      url +
      '/example-1/rest-api/persons';
    return this.httpService.get<Person[]>(url, headers);
}
```

The Java SpringBoot Backend:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/persons", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> getPersons(@Context final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
      @RequestHeader("Authorization") final String authorization) throws Exception {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.service.getPersons());
  }
```

UPDATE:
Rest Endpoint is now returning a list with the class Person instead of String, but this did not help.

Comment: I would like to see the response from the backend, I assume that this does not return a JSON object. But you expect `applciation/json`  for your `Content-Type` in `HttpHeaders`.

Comment: Extensions might interfere with network requests. try to disable any extensions you have installed and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I added the backend code. I am dont have the rights to remove the plugin. I have one SSO plugin activated. However on other angular appliations it is not making any problems :/

Comment: Can you change `return this.httpService.get<string[]>(url, headers);` to `return this.httpService.get<Person[]>(url, headers);` - Where `Person` is a Interface.

Comment: The endpoint is returning a Person now as a class, but this did not help unfortunately.

Comment: Single Person Ort a List?

Comment: I updated my question, there you can see the code. I returned a list of Persons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post your 'httpService' source code.
Also I've noticed that you have a typo in your 'Content-Type' header value:

```
.set('Content-Type', 'applciation/json')
```

Should be:

```
.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

In the meantime you can try this:

```
public getPersons(): Observable<string[]> {
    const headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_token}`
    });
    return this.http.get(apiUrl, { headers: headers });
}
```

Comment: it seems that this solved the issue. Hence this is an irregular error I will test again the next days. Thanks so far for your help :)